# Annotating mismatches in regular expression

Tags: regex

I need to "annotate" with a X character each mismatch in a regular expression, For example if I have a text file like:

```
Line1Name: this is a (string).
Line2Name: (a string)
Line3Name this is a line without parenthesis
Line4Name: (a string 2)
```

Now following regular expression will match everything before a :

```
^[^:]+(?=:)
```

so the result will be

```
Line1Name:
Line2Name:
Line4Name:
```

However I would need to annotate the mismatch at the 3rd line, having this output:

```
Line1Name: 
Line2Name:
X
Line4Name:
```

Is this possible with regular expressions?

Comment: You may try a scripting language to find whether its not matched using the regular expression given.

Comment: `awk '/^[^:]+:/ { print $1; next } { print "X" }' file`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at what a regular expression is, you will realize that it is not possible to do logical operations with a regex alone. Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

> In computing, a regular expression provides a concise and flexible means to “match” (**specify and recognize**) strings of text, such as particular characters, words, or patterns of characters.

emphasis mine – simply put, a regex is a fancy way to find a string; it either does (it matches), or not.

To achieve what you are after, you need some kind of logic switch that operates on the match / not-match result of your regex search and triggers an action. You haven’t specified in what environment you are using your regex, so providing a solution is a bit pointless, but as an example, this would do what you are trying to do in pure `bash`:

```
# assuming your string is in $str
result="$([[ $str =~ ^[^:]+: ]] && echo "${str%:*}" || echo "X")"
```

and this does the same thing in a language supporting your regex pattern (Ruby):

```
# assuming your string is in str
result = str.match(/^[^:]+(?=:)/) || "X"
```

*As a side note, your example code does not match the output: you are using a lookahead for the colon, which excludes it in the match, but your output includes it. I’ve opted for sticking with your regex over your output pattern in my examples, thus excluding the colon from the result.*

Comment: You use 2 techniques in bash solution: regex matching to test and pattern matching to echo, it would be more comprehensible just to use BASH_REMATCH in my opinion.

Comment: @nshy: true as to clearness of the statement, but I would have to use pattern matching on BASH_REMATCH instead to get rid of the trailing colon if I did that (see last para of my answer on why I omit the colon from the match) as [extended regexes do not support lookahead assertions](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man7/re_format.7.html).